# Android Facebook request taking too long

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have basically copy/pasted this code from the Facebook API tutorials but when I run it, it can take over 60(!) seconds to call onCompleted() which is obviously totally unacceptable. I have had it take less than 10 seconds a couple times but that is very rare; most of the time it takes at least 30 seconds. This wouldn't be affected by my local framerate right? I am loading textures and rendering a loading screen while this request is pending which causes some choppyness in the rendering but I wouldn't think that would affect this. I have also tried the emulator as well as multiple different phones and all have the same problem. If anyone has any ideas or suggestions please help!

```
 Session.openActiveSession( this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
        {
            if( session != null && session.isOpened() )
            {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request request = Request.newMeRequest( session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                            // callback after Graph API response with user object

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                            {
                                 // sometimes over 60 seconds to get here!
                            }
                        }
                        );
                Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
Session.openActiveSession( this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
        {
            if( session != null && session.isOpened() )
            {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request request = Request.executeMeRequest( session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                            // callback after Graph API response with user object

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                            {}
                        });
            }
        }
    });
```